# Magento - Authorize.net Payment gateway test account not working

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am new to Magento Application.

I am  getting *warning alert message* (with below bold text) when PLACing ORDER in **Magento** application for testing a transaction in Authoriz.Net with the following credit card  credentials.

```
CC No.: 4111111111111111    
Exp Date: Any future month and year    
CVV: Any 3 digits number.
```

**The credit card did not pass the address verification check. Please check your address details and resubmit.**

Please help me to check my Test transaction in Magento. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Test Credit Card numbers** [(source)](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php#test-credit-card-numbers)

> Set the expiration date to anytime in the future.

- > `American Express Test Card` => **370000000000002**
- > `Discover Test Card`        => **6011000000000012**
- > `Visa Test Card`            => **4007000000027**
- > `Second Visa Test Card`     => **4012888818888**
- > `JCB`                       => **3088000000000017**
- > `Diners Club/ Carte Blanche` => **38000000000006**

Answer (score 0):

Adding more information under this question, here is a very easy and great article talking about how to configure a authorize.net test account and the rest of the configuration part under magento. I'm using to test authorize.net this following test info:
Type: VISA
cc number: 41111111111111111(I don't remember if are 15 or 16 number 1)
Cvv: 123

Best,
Alejandro.